# try to run mapReduce jar file with Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, executable-jar

I am trying to use java to write a MapReduce function to count the words in a csv file. 
I am able to successfully build the project and I manage to create a jar file.
I'm using Hadoop for running everything and I successfully install it on my PC, manage to upload the csv file to hadoop server but when I try to run this command:

```
hadoop jar C:/MRProgramsDemo.jar PackageDemo.WordCount wordCountFile MRDir1
```

I keep getting the following error message:

[image: The error I kepp getting]

try to run other programs I found online and other jar file but without succses. can anybody no what I do wrong?

Comment: Well, does that input path exist if you run `hdfs dfs -ls /user`? Typically package names are not capitalized

Comment: it's output 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Did you ever make a user directory? That error is telling you it doesn't exist

Comment: no... I have tmp directory automatically created but no user firectory. But I dont try the user directory so why ask for?

Comment: By default, `wordCountFile` as an input parameter will search your user folder for that filepath... If you want to look at the root of HDFS, where you put the file, the leading slash is required, as my answer says

Comment: so you're sayin that I need to open a user directory? or that the hadoop The installation was not good and that why I dont have a user drictory?
If I try 'hadoop jar C:/MRProgramsDemo_1.7.jar /user /wordcountFile' (after I opened a /user directory) it's still output error. I'm sorry for the hard question but I new to this and having a hard time to find any help and every tutorial I try never sayed any thing about a user directory

Comment: Never said anything? `hadoop fs -ls /user/joe/wordcount/input/` ... mentioned in the official documentation https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html  Again, you need your **own** user folder. `hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/Anil-PC`, then `hdfs dfs -put file.csv` will upload that to your user folder, which you can run `hdfs dfs -ls` to see that (notice I didn't specify a folder to list)... But **none of that matters** if you had `-put file.csv /wordCountFile`, as shown in your question.

Comment: Basically, start with `hdfs dfs -ls /`, if your file is there, then you need to give that full path (starting with `/` as the input directory), if not, then move down to `/user`, then `/user/Anil-PC`, which needs to exist anyway and you need to make it if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.

First, you put the file at the root of HDFS, not your user folder, therefore, the parameter must be `/wordCountFile`

Second, it looks like you've made an executable JAR, so you can remove the class name from the parameters

Comment: Already try with '/' the first time but still getting error. The class name is from a tutorial I found and try but still getting error

Comment: Try `hadoop jar C:/MRProgramsDemo.jar  /wordCountFile /MRDir1`... What errors do you get?

Comment: Well, that file path should exist assuming `hadoop fs -put file.csv /wordCountFile` worked, as shown in your first image